# How to get Integer from button title

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a Button labeled "3x3" now I want to create an Int variable with the value "3" in button click function.

I have tried

```
let newBoardSizeString = String.localizedStringWithFormat("\(sender.currentTitle?.characters.first)")
let newBoardSize = Int(newBoardSizeString)
```

The string i get is like this

```
"Optional(\"3\")"
```

and Int I get is

```
nil
```

I want only 3

Comment: `Int(newBoardSizeString)!`

Comment: Why would you want to create an Int from a button label?

Comment: because I want to call another function which has an Int as argument

Comment: I mean, if you know it is 3 then just pass 3. If the button label is set dynamically, the number 3 should be from somewhere else and you should take that value from there, not from the button label.

Comment: @Mr.Bista it doesn't work

Comment: @ThanhPham I have 6 other buttons with labels like 6x6, 4x4 etc

Comment: That's not a good approach to set the button label (the UI) first and then get the data from them. You should consider creating the data first then populating the UI with that data. For example, create an array [3, 6, 4] and then set the button labels using string format.

Comment: I'm not setting button label dynamically.

Comment: @NiravD I did but String() doesn't work it gives a fix suggestion like String(describing: sender.currentTitle?.characters.dropLast(2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You ask: "How do I convert the first character of my button label to an Int."

The real answer is "Don't do that." It is a very bad idea to make the logic of your code depend on display information.

One simple solution is to use the tag property of your button and set the tag value to 3 in IB when you create the button:

```
let newBoardSize = sender.tag
```

Note that you either need to set your IBAction up with the sender as type UIButton (the better solution) or cast sender to the correct class in your IBAction.

Another approach is to set up outlets to your different buttons (e.g. `threeButton` and `fourButton`) and then in your IBAction, check which button is the sender and use a switch statement to figure out the appropriate value for each button:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
  switch sender {
     case threeButton:
       //Use the value 3
     case fourButton
       //Use the value 4
   }
}
```

Comment: Finally, someone makes an answer as answers should be!

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
let newBoardSize = newBoardSizeString as! Int
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newBoardSizeString = String.localizedStringWithFormat("\(sender.currentTitle?.characters.first)")
if let unwrapped = Int(newBoardSizeString){
    let newBoardSize = unwrapped
}
```

Answer (score 0):

!

```
 let newBoardSizeString = String.localizedStringWithFormat("\(sender.currentTitle?.characters.first!)")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ?

```
 Int(newBoardSizeString)!
```

and make sure you are handling the `nil` before unwrapping the value.